# Generate HTML file with R using Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, html

I try to display the France map on HTML with RStudio; I followed the tutorial to the World card in [Creating an interactive map with Leaflet](http://rgeomatic.hypotheses.org/date/2015/05); Example works.

I wanted to do the same just by displaying the map of France:
code:

```r
library(rgdal) 
library(foreign)
library(maptools)

FRA=readShapePoly("/Users/insa/Documents/exempleR/FRA_adm/FRA_adm0.shp")

#plot(FRA_adm0)
# Nettoyage des données

library(leaflet)
## Initialisation 
m <- leaflet(padding = 0)
## Ajout des pays

## Ajout des pays
m <- addPolygons(map = m, data = FRA, opacity = 100, 
                 color = "#FAFCFA", 
                 weight = 0.25,popup = NULL,
                 options = list(clickable = FALSE), 
                 fill = T, fillColor = "#B3C4B3", 
                 fillOpacity = 100)

## Dimensions de la carte
m$width <- 874
m$height <- 700


# Export de la carte en html
library(htmlwidgets)
saveWidget(m, 'mapfrance.html', selfcontained = TRUE)
```

error:

```
Stack space overflow: current size 33632 bytes.
Use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it.
Erreur : pandoc document conversion failed with error 2
```

I do not understand this error, is that it's the input file is shapefile .shpaand not .rdata?

Comment: This should be fixed with the latest `htmlwidgets` package. Try updating and/or installing from github. If you still get an error (I do not btw) then you can set the `pandoc.stack.size` option mentioned here: https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/commit/299010a3747a9f8df37ee9c3fa041deb4ae50b4f

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to set the **`selfcontained`** variable to **`FALSE`**. That worked for me. Beside that make sure that the Shape of France is saved with the coordinate system  **WGS 84** (*EPSG:4326*).

```r
# install packages
install.packages(c("rgdal", "maptools", "leaflet", "htmlwidgets"), dependencies = TRUE)

# load libraries
library("rgdal")
library("maptools")
library("leaflet")
library("htmlwidgets")

# load france as shape
FRA=readShapePoly("data/france.shp")

# Initialsation
m <- leaflet(padding = 0)

# Add country
m <- addPolygons(map = m, data = FRA, opacity = 100, 
                 color = "#FAFCFA", 
                 weight = 0.25,popup = NULL,
                 options = list(clickable = FALSE), 
                 fill = T, fillColor = "#B3C4B3", 
                 fillOpacity = 100)

# Dimention of the map
m$width <- 874
m$height <- 700


# Export as HTML file
saveWidget(m, 'mapfrance.html', selfcontained = FALSE)
```

[image: leaflet france]

#### EDIT

After the [hint](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171827/generate-html-file-with-r-using-leaflet/171843#comment256659_171827) of [@hrbrmstr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171827/generate-html-file-with-r-using-leaflet#comment256659_171827) above I check my package version:

```r
packageVersion("htmlwidgets")
[1] ‘0.5’
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not mind about background maps, maybe you want to have a look at **mapview** (although the package does not support automated storing of created maps yet).

```
## required packages
library(mapview)
library(raster)

## get shapefile
FRA <- getData(country = "FRA", level = "0")

## create interactive map
m <- mapview(FRA)
m
```

[image: france]

For now, the best workaround to retrieve the created map is to locate the temporary folder where all the output from your `mapview()` call is stored. You can type `tempfile()` into the R console to figure out the general path to the temporary folders created from R (on my linux machine it looks like this - "/tmp/RtmpzMzJv7/file..."). There you should find a folder that was created by `mapview()` (they are usually called something like "viewhtml..." with "..." being some random string of numbers and letters). There you should find an "index.html" file and one or more folders. You can simply copy all contents to a folder of your liking and open "index.html" from there.

Unfortunately, function `plainview` - which creates maps without displaying background maps - currently supports 'Raster*' objects only, but we hope to implement a version for polygons (and all other kinds of shapefiles) soon.