# how to display simple arrow on the map in R using Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, html

I try to display an  arrow on the map using R and the `leaflet` package,

code of map see my [related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/171827):

```r
# install packages
install.packages(c("rgdal", "maptools", "leaflet", "htmlwidgets"), dependencies = TRUE)

# load libraries
library("rgdal")
library("maptools")
library("leaflet")
library("htmlwidgets")

# load france as shape
FRA=readShapePoly("data/france.shp")

# Initialsation
m <- leaflet(padding = 0)

# Add country
m <- addPolygons(map = m, data = FRA, opacity = 100, 
                 color = "#FAFCFA", 
                 weight = 0.25,popup = NULL,
                 options = list(clickable = FALSE), 
                 fill = T, fillColor = "#B3C4B3", 
                 fillOpacity = 100)

# Dimention of the map
m$width <- 874
m$height <- 700

# Export as HTML file
saveWidget(m, 'mapfrance.html', selfcontained = FALSE)
```

code of arrow :

```r
x<-c(2.484722,-8.445833)
y<-c(51.5085300,10.50306)
i <- order(x, y); x <- x[i]; y <- y[i]
## draw arrows from point to point :
s <- seq(length(x)-1)  # one shorter than data
plot(FRA)
points(x,y)
arrows(x[s], y[s], x[s+1], y[s+1], col = 1:3,angle = 20)
```

how can I display a simple arrow on the map?

Comment: Did you already take a look at examples, or implemented solutions? Like http://meteotest.github.io/leaflet-arrows/

Comment: it's json, how to execute from R?

Comment: As of 2022, leaflet.minicharts seems to provide this feature, see [addFlows](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet.minicharts/versions/0.6.2/topics/addFlows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just write the **r** plots into your map output. Check [leaflet for R](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/) for more details.

*The best solution would be to use the json arrow as said from [@nebi](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171904/how-to-display-simple-arrow-on-the-map-in-r-using-leaflet#comment256847_171904), but I also don't know how to implement it into **r**.*

---

Another solution is to write a function which returns you the coordinates of an arrowhead and then just draw some lines (see example below). *The arrowhead doesn't look too nice 'cuz of the use of longitudes and latitudes for the calculation. But anyway it works.*

```r
# install packages
install.packages(c("rgdal", "maptools", "leaflet", "htmlwidgets"), dependencies = TRUE)

# load libraries
library("rgdal")
library("maptools")
library("leaflet")
library("htmlwidgets")

# function get arrowhead() returns coordinates of a the arrowhead of a line
get_arrowhead <- function (fromPoint, toPoint){

  # dx,dy = arrow line vector
  dx <- toPoint$x - fromPoint$x;
  dy <- toPoint$y - fromPoint$y;

  # normalize
  length <- sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  unitDx <- dx / length;
  unitDy <- dy / length;

  # increase this to get a larger arrow head
  arrowHeadBoxSize = 1;

  arrowPoint1 <- list(x = (toPoint$x - unitDx * arrowHeadBoxSize - unitDy * arrowHeadBoxSize),
                      y = (toPoint$y - unitDy * arrowHeadBoxSize + unitDx * arrowHeadBoxSize));
  arrowPoint2 <- list(x = (toPoint$x - unitDx * arrowHeadBoxSize + unitDy * arrowHeadBoxSize),
                      y = (toPoint$y - unitDy * arrowHeadBoxSize - unitDx * arrowHeadBoxSize));

  return( mapply(c, arrowPoint1, toPoint, arrowPoint2) )

}

# load france as 
FRA=readShapePoly("france.shp")

m <- leaflet(padding = 0)

# Add country
m <- addPolygons(map = m, data = FRA, opacity = 100, 
                 color = "#FAFCFA", 
                 weight = 0.25,popup = NULL,
                 options = list(clickable = FALSE), 
                 fill = T, fillColor = "#B3C4B3", 
                 fillOpacity = 100)

x<-c(2.484722,-8.445833)
y<-c(51.5085300,10.50306)
i <- order(x, y); x <- x[i]; y <- y[i]

fromPoint <- list (x = x[1], y = y[1])
toPoint <- list (x = x[2], y = y[2])

# get coordinates of arrowhead
arrowhead <- get_arrowhead (fromPoint, toPoint)

# draw points
m <- addCircles(map = m, lng = x, lat = y, weight = 1, radius = 1000)

# draw polyline
m <- addPolylines(map = m, lng = x, lat = y ) # arrow line
m <- addPolylines(map = m, arrow_data[,"x"], lat = arrow_data[,"y"] ) # arrow head

# Dimention of the map
m$width <- 874
m$height <- 700

# Export as HTML file
saveWidget(m, 'mapfrance.html', selfcontained = FALSE)
```

[image: map france with arrow example]

Comment: @witich : how to add the angle to show the direction of arrows , it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment, but you could create an icon and use addMarker

check this out : https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html